# Sum all combinations of 2 columns from 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, combinations

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2 (same index and number of rows), and I would like to create a new dataframe which columns are the sum of all combinations of 2 columns from df1 and df2, example :

**input :**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 =  pd.DataFrame([[10,20]])
df2 =  pd.DataFrame([[1,2]])
```

**output :**

```
import pandas as pd
df3 =  pd.DataFrame([[11,12,21,22]])
```

Comment: what would be the output for `df1 =  pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30,40]])` and `df2 =  pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]])`?

Comment: @mozway -  a dataframe with 16 columns [[11,12,...,43,44]]

Comment: OK, then it is indeed a product ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) for all combinations and sum DataFrames with repeated values by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, df2.columns])

df = df1.reindex(mux, level=0, axis=1) + df2.reindex(mux, level=1, axis=1)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks this works when I replace the second df1 in the first line with df2

Comment: @AJM7564 - Super, answer was changed.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do this with numpy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n = df1.shape[1]
>>> pd.DataFrame(df1.values.repeat(n) + np.tile(df2.values, n))
    0   1   2   3
0  11  12  21  22
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. This does not work for 2 dataframes with different number of columns (it does when I replace "df1.values.repeat(n)" with "df1.values.repeat(df2.shape[1])"). It also does not work for dataframes with more tahn 1 row (maybe a reshape would help).